# Handling Inter Class Memory Deallocation in C++

Tags: c++, memory-management, machine-learning, neural-network

I am implementing Artificial Neural Network in C++ for my Machine Learning course. Here's my code for "Neuron" -

```
struct Neuron
{
    float *inputs;          // pointer to inputs array
    int inputCount;         // number of input
    float *weights;
    float sum;              // linear weight sum of inputs
    float output = 0.0;     // output from activation function

    float bias = 1.0;

    float delta;            // error gradient


    Neuron(){}

    Neuron(int inputCount)
    {
        this->inputCount = inputCount;
        this->weights = new float [inputCount];

        InitializeWeights();
    }


    float ActivationFunction(float x)
    {
        return 1.0 / (1.0 + exp(-x));
    }

    void Calculate(float *inputs)
    {
        this->inputs = inputs;

        float temp = 0.0;

        for(int i=0; i<inputCount; i++)
        {
            temp += weights[i] * inputs[i];
        }

        temp += bias;
        sum = temp;
        output = ActivationFunction(sum);
    }

    void InitializeWeights()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<inputCount; i++)
        {
            weights[i] = rand() % 101 / 100;
        }
    }

    ~Neuron()
    {
        delete[] weights;
    }

};
```

I also have another struct called "Layer" which represents a layer. The neurons are  initialized there as -

```
for(int i=0; i<neuronCount; i++)
{
    neurons[i] = Neuron(inputCount);
}
```

where "neuronCount" is the number of neurons in the layer. The problem is that the weight array in the neurons is immediately deallocated because of destructor calling. What should I do to prevent this? More importantly, is there any better way to design my program?

Comment: Could you please provide the source of "Layer" class ?

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use `std::vector<float>` instead of `float *` and `new [] / delete[]`.  All of your problems with this code would be solved if you did this.  Otherwise you need to implement the [rule of 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Comment: Is it going out of scope? why the destructors are called? And can you try heap based allocations? but do remember to delete those.

Comment: To prevent this, you could follow the "rule of three" (you've failed to provide an assignment operator and copy constructor), but it's better to use `std::vector` and follow the "rule of zero". (Also, your default constructor is broken; destroying a default-initialised object is undefined.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things wrong with your code.

The first is that you failed to initialize your `input` and `weights` pointers in the default constructor.  Thus the following simple program would cause an issue:

```
int main()
{
  Neuron n;
}
```

Since the destructor for `n` would be attempting to call `delete []` on an uninitialized pointer `weights`.

The other problem is that your `Neuron` class is not safely copyable or assignable.  The following program will also show problems with memory leaks and double deletion errors:

```
int main()
{
    Neuron n(10);
    Neuron n2 = n;  // copy constructor
    Neuron n3(2);
    n = n3;         // assignment
}   // memory leaks, double deletion issues once main() exits.
```

The third issue is that you're passing a pointer to `float` in your `Calculate` function, and you have no idea if the pointer is valid inside of that function, or even if it is valid, how many items the `inputs` pointer is representing.  If the number is less than the number of `weights`, your code has a memory overrun attempting to access `inputs[i]` once `i` goes out-of-bounds of the `input`.

To fix these issues, the easiest thing to do is to use `std::vector`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>

struct Neuron
{
    std::vector<float> inputs;          // pointer to inputs array
    std::vector<float> weights;
    float sum = 0;              // linear weight sum of inputs
    float output = 0.0;     // output from activation function
    float bias = 1.0;
    float delta = 0;            // error gradient

    Neuron() {}
    Neuron(int inputCount) : weights(inputCount) 
    {
        InitializeWeights();
    }

    float ActivationFunction(float x)
    {
        return 1.0 / (1.0 + exp(-x));
    }

    void Calculate(const std::vector<float>& inputs_)
    {
        inputs = inputs_;

        // make sure vectors are the same size.  If inputs is smaller,
        // the new elements added will be 0
        inputs.resize(weights.size());

        // use inner_product to get the sum of the products.
        sum = std::inner_product(std::begin(weights), 
                                 std::end(weights), 
                                 std::begin(inputs), 0.0f) + bias;

        output = ActivationFunction(sum);
    }

    void InitializeWeights()
    {
        std::generate(std::begin(weights), std::end(weights), rand() % 101 / 100);
    }
};
```

Note we no longer use pointers, as the `std::vector` takes care of the memory management.  We also don't need to have member variables that keep track of the count (such as `inputCount`), since a vector knows its own size by using `vector::size()`.

In addition, the [std::inner_product](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/inner_product) is used to generate the sum in the `Calculate` function (after resizing the `input` vector to the same size as `weights`).  The `inputs_` is passed to `Calculate` as a `std::vector`, thus you can call it using a brace initialized list:

```
someInstance.Calculate({9.8, 5.6, 4.5}); // calls Calculate with a vector consisting of 3 items.
```

Also, the `InitializeWeights` function calls the [std::generate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate) algorithm function to set the `weights` vector.

---

If you were not to use `std::vector`, then your class would require a copy constructor and assignment operator, following the [Rule of 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).  I won't go over how you would fix your class without using `vector`, as the answer would get more involved.

---

The last item is that usage of `rand()` in C++ should be replaced with usage of the [C++11 random number facilities](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random).

Comment: Thank you very much for your excellent and detailed answer. Greatly appreciate your efforts to correct my mistakes.